# Cannot add additional server from the Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, server

Can some of you can help me with this.

What I have to do:

I have to publish my code from my local machine to the server. I found that I have to add the current server in the Server Explorer(to be able to create a Publish profile "method File System" and in the xml file to show the path of where to publish my code on the server).
But I cannot add this server on my Server Explorer.

What I tried:

1.Remote debugging - not working

2.stop the firewall - not working

3.Tried with the Name of the Server and the IP

The error that I receive is :
Could not reconnect to "Static". Make Sure that the machine name and path are valid.

I will be really happy if somebody can help me!

Comment: This seems to be more of a Visual Studio problem than a SQL problem, please add some tags indicating the visual studio version used.

Comment: I use VS 2013 Ultimate with update 5